# What does this sentence from a Computer Book mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a book and am stuck with a particular sentence:

> One other significant change is that the Pentium Pro processor uses
>   three execution engines, so it can execute up to three instructions at
>   a time, *which can conflict and still execute in parallel*.

I understand the meaning till "three instructions at a time".

What does the rest of sentence mean?

I think it means that when instructions have a conflict, they execute in parallel. Am I right? Is it possible to translate this into something simpler?

Comment: The three instructions can conflict between each other. Despite this, they still will be executed in a parallel manner. The conflict will not prevent their parallel execution.

Comment: You can't really understand this without understanding the general concept of a "multiprocessor" computer.  And the part about "conflict" gets real messy real fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple rewrite that avoids separating the "which" from its referent (by avoiding the "which" :-)

One other significant change is that the Pentium Pro processor uses three execution engines, so it can execute up to three instructions *in parallel, even if they conflict with each other*.

Answer (score 0):

> One other significant change is that the Pentium Pro processor uses three execution engines, so it can execute up to three instructions at a time, **which can conflict and still execute in parallel**.

As @CopperKettle says,

> Even if the three instructions conflict with each other, they will still be executed parallely

or

I'd put it this way:

> Regardless of conflicts, the three instructions will be executed in parallel.